# rails redirecting from expired assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, csrf

I have a rails (4.1) app running on Heroku with cloudflare as the CDN.  In the error logs from NewRelic I see a constant trickle of requests for expired css and js assets, primarily `application-<fingerprint>.js` and `application-<fingerprint>.css`(with fingerprints that have been expired).

I am wondering about a solution to redirect these requests to the current asset but I am uncertain if this is a good/safe thing to do.

In my routes I'd add

```ruby
get "assets/:asset_name" => "assets#show"
```

and then add an assets_controller.rb with:

```ruby
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:show]

  def show    
    begin
      asset_name = params[:asset_name].gsub(/-[0-9a-f]{32}$/, "") << ".#{params[:format]}"

      if ["css", "js"].include?(params[:format])
        redirect_to "/assets/" + Rails.application.assets.find_asset(asset_name).digest_path
      else
        return asset_not_found!
      end

    rescue
      return asset_not_found!
    end
  end

  private

  def asset_not_found!
    render :text => "asset #{params[:asset_name]}.#{params[:format]} not found", :status => 404
  end

end
```

I've tried this out on a stage environment and it works but I'm not sure if this is the right way.
In particular the need to have `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` bothers me, but without it requests for .js assets result in a InvalidCrossOriginRequest error.

I only see requests for expired css and js assets, not for any image assets, hence the above check for the request format being either "css" or "js", but maybe that's an unnecessary step.

So my question is; would doing this be bad practice? Is there a better way to handle requests for expired assets?

Answer (score 0):

i consider this a bad practice.

not particular the way that you implemented id (even though i think there are better ways using rack middlewares), but more because of the fact that you should not redirect those expired assets anywhere.

if a user requests a css or js file with a stale fingerprint they likely have a html document that is out of date and you will probably want him to reload what he has: "there is a new version, please reload your site".

deploying is taken care of at heroku since sprockets stores up to 3 versions of the assets for you https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#only-generate-digest-assets

Comment: Thanks @phoet. I thought this wasn't right!  What would you suggest doing with these requests? I guess part of the problem is I have a route for get ":username/:post_name" so an asset which isn't recognised hit's that route with the :username as "assets" and the :post_name" as something like "application-[fingerprint].js" which either causes an InvalidCrossOriginRequest error for .js or an UnknownFormat error for .css.